# byte array of sound data from Windows Phone 7 to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, windows-phone-7, audio

I am trying to post a bytes of sound data from Windows Phone 7 to an App Engine Java servlet. Somewhere along the way the data gets screwed up and when I try to play the audio it doesn't work. Here is some of the code:

WP7:

```
public static void SendEmail(byte[] data, String to, String subject, String filename)
    {
        //WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        //wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/binary";
        String url = "http://someserver/test?to=" + to + "&subject=" + subject + "&filename=" + filename;
        //wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url), "POST");

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", data);
        webClient.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenWriteCompleted);
    }

    static void webClient_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] objArr = e.UserState as object[];
        byte[] fileContent = e.UserState as byte[];

        Stream outputStream = e.Result;
        outputStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        outputStream.Flush();
        outputStream.Close();
    }
```

App Engine Servlet:

```
InputStream in = req.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int next = in.read();
while (next > -1) {
  bos.write(next);
  next = in.read();
}       
bos.flush();
attachmentData = bos.toByteArray();
```

Wp7 audio code:

```
microphone.GetData(buffer);

stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
//then I save the stream.toArray() to an object and use it later for playback on the   phone
```

Java code for creating the audio (audio is sent as an attachment on an email):

```
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachmentPart.setFileName(filename + ".wav");
        attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
        DataSource src = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachmentData, "audio/x-wav");
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(src);
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(handler);
        mp.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the input and output byte arrays - or at least their lengths - to see what's happening?

Comment: I noticed too that when the data gets written out to the ByteArrayOutputStream it changes the values. If I skip that part and just put the values straight in the attachmentData array, I get an "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"255" Radix:10" exception

Comment: I don't know much about audio/x-wave, but I don't this is going to work. The binary data is only one part of the wave file (it's the raw audio data). All raw audio data lives within a "container". Typical WAV files are RIFF containers. So you will likely need to write a RIFF header and write all the bytes in appropriate chunks to ensure the file is written properly (WAV's have a specific file format). Here's more information on the WAV file format: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html. I don't thin kaudio/x-wave does that for you (I could be wrong)

Comment: If you are comfortable with C/C++ code, there is a Media Foundation (Windows API) example of writing a WAVE file (that shows writing the header and chunks): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757929(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question - have you compared the data? How does it differ? Also, what @Jason said - are you sure the data you're sending is a complete sound file, not just the PCM data? Where are you getting your data from?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware of your [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). I don't really know much about Google App Engine, but I'm guess that your servlet is Java code and the Windows Phone 7 code is C#? Since you are reading ints (4 bytes) on the app engine servlet, and writing bytes on the WP7 side, my first guess is that you are writing the bytes in one endianness and reading in another. If that is the case, you will either have to change the endianness when you're writing the bytes on the WP7 side (does WP7 have the BitConverter class?), or "switch" bytes on the other side to ensure the correct endianness.

Also, as a clarification, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it play audio that's just garbled? Or is it silent? Etc.

One step to debug the endianness, is write a single integer (in the form of bytes) on the WP7 side, and read that integer on the App Engine side. Is it the same integer? If not, you are having an endianness issue.

Comment: What happens is the audio file is not recognized as valid and won't play. I have been watching the values of the byte array on both sides and sometimes they are the same and sometimes not.

Comment: Few more questions... :) How are you playing the file? What type of file/data is it? Is it simply a WAV file? MP3? Etc. Also, how are you generating/getting the data on the WP7 side? Is it simply a raw binary copy of an entire existing file? Or is it just the audio data you're sending? If it's just the audio data, are you writing the correct "container" to disk as well (most formats require headers and the like, not just the raw audio data)?

Comment: I am trying to create a .wav file. I added some more code above. I noticed too that when the data gets written out to the ByteArrayOutputStream it changes the values. If I skip that part and just put the values straight in the attachmentData array, I get an "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"255" Radix:10" exception

Comment: Okay, let's take the attachment out of the equation to make sure the endianness is correct. I'd send 8 bytes across the wire (two integers). Then just read the integers on the other side and put them directly in the email (for "debugging" purposes). Are the numbers the same or are they different? If they're different, you have an endian issue (I'd try one small integer, and one very large integer).

Comment: As I mentioned before, the values are the same until I write them out to the ByteArrayOutputStream. And I don't really have to create a wav file. It could be any kind of audio that will work.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an audio file in c# and then upload the entire file to the server?

Comment: That's probably what I would do. It would take any cross-language/cross-platform endian issues out of the equation. There are some links in this SO question (on writing WAV files): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543335/reading-writing-wav-riff-tags. You'll have to write the RIFF chunks. You can probably use an InMemoryStream to write out the RIFF chunks and then post the entire stream of bytes to the server. Like I mentioned in a different comment, I think it's cause you're only writing the audio data and not the entire RIFF format (so it's not a valid WAV file).

Comment: Endianness doesn't really apply when you're talking about an octet stream.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the wave header to your file? The raw bytes from the microphone are not a wave file by themselves. You ned to add teh proper RIFF header that among other things contains information the number of channels, bytes per sample, sample rate, encoding, and some other bits. I put an article on CodeProject.com that contains  the code you need. It's in a voice recorder. Also check out the comments area as there is a reference to a streaming recorder there.