# Post audio file from WP7 to App Engine server(Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-phone-7, audio, attachment, wav

I have a Windows Phone 7 app (QuickNote) that allows users to record voice notes. I am trying to add a feature that will let users email their audio notes as an attachment. I use the XNA audio library to play the voice notes on the phone and I save the raw audio (a byte array) on an object so it can be played back.

I need to be able to create an audio file(.wav, .mp3, or whatever) and post it to an App Engine java servlet that I created so that I can email the audio file as an attachment.

Any direction and/or code samples is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768385/byte-array-of-sound-data-from-windows-phone-7-to-app-engine ?

Comment: Nope. There I was asking how to get raw audio data to app engine and create a file out of it. Now I'm asking how to send a file. Thanks for your concern though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the java part, but I have the client part - from my post at http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SelectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoChooserTask task = new PhotoChooserTask();
        task.Completed += task_Completed;
        task.Show();
    }

    private void task_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
            return;

        const int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:4223/File/Upload", UriKind.Absolute);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        wc.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

        // what to do when write stream is open
        wc.OpenWriteCompleted += (s, args) =>
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(args.Result))
                {
                    long bCount = 0;
                    long fileSize = e.ChosenPhoto.Length;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = br.ReadBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
                        bCount += bytes.Length;
                        bw.Write(bytes);
                    } while (bCount < fileSize);
                }
            }
        };

        // what to do when writing is complete
        wc.WriteStreamClosed += (s, args) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Send Complete");
        };

        // Write to the WebClient
        wc.OpenWriteAsync(uri, "POST");
    }
}
```

Basially you just run an HTTP POST to some URL. In the example from my blog, I'm posting to an ASP.NET MVC Controller Action, which just takes in the incoming input stream and writes it to disk.

Hopeully this helps. If you are having problems with the java side, let me know and I'll see if I can't rustle up a sample for that too.

/chris